# Vuforia (Unity created Xcode project) shows blank screen after adding to existing Xcode app

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, vuforia, xcode10

I added Xcode Unity AR (with Vuforia) project to existing Xcode app by [this tutorial](https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity). I have few problems but I solved them all and my project is now building and running in real device. App works as before but when I try to select AR item from menu so my controller with Unity AR is pushed. I get blank screen (white screen). These are few lines from console log (that I think are related to problem):

```
User pre-granted access to the camera
[6669:1320892] INFO/AR(6669) 2018-09-27 10:08:15: Vuforia selected rendering API OpenGL ES 2.x
[6669:1320892] INFO/AR(6669) 2018-09-27 10:08:15: Vuforia SDK version 7.2.23
[6669:1320892] INFO/AR(6669) 2018-09-27 10:08:15: Vuforia Fusion: Detected and enabled use of ARKit
[6669:1320892] Rendering mode set to: OpenGL ES 2.0
[6669:1320892] Rendering mode set to: OpenGL ES 2.0
[6669:1320892] DEBUG/AR(6669) Could not find a UIView with CAEAGLLayer or CAMetalLayer layer class that responds to selector renderFrameVuforia
[6669:1320892] DEBUG/AR(6669) UIView has CAEAGLLayer layer class
[6669:1320892] DEBUG/AR(6669) UIView does not respond to selector renderFrameVuforia
[6669:1320892] DEBUG/AR(6669) UIView has CAEAGLLayer layer class
[6669:1320892] DEBUG/AR(6669) UIView does not respond to selector renderFrameVuforia
[6669:1320892] DEBUG/AR(6669) Could not find a UIView with CAEAGLLayer or CAMetalLayer layer class that responds to selector renderFrameVuforia
Vuforia initialization successful
...
[6669:1320892] ERROR/AR(6669) 2018-09-27 10:08:16: Cannot setMode to AR before Camera is initialized
Dataset ARBoxes could not be loaded and cannot be activated.
...
cameraDeviceStartCamera
[6669:1320892] INFO/AR(6669) 2018-09-27 10:08:16: Starting camera with profile for iPhone10,4, 720.1
[6669:1320892] ERROR/AR(6669) 2018-09-27 10:08:16: VideoBackgroundConfig with screen size of zero received, skipping config step
```

More info about versions:

- Xcode 10
- iPhone 8 (iOS 12)
- Unity 2018.2.9
- Vuforia 7.2.23

I tried to change many settings according to many forum posts that I found but nothing helps me. I am not using Metal (I am using OpenGLES3, I tried OpenGLES2 too).

Thanks for help

Comment: Does your Unity scene shown when you show your controller with Unity? Probably your problem is not in Vuforia, but in integrating Unity into native app? You can add simple scene in Unity and check if your intergation works (that your simple scene is presentable in native app)

Answer (score 0):

> ***ARKit is an up-to-date framework*** and it was designed to use `Metal`/`SceneKit` rendering extensively, not an `OpenGL ES`. Mixing `ARSCNView` with `OpenGL ES 2.x` rendering seems very very bad idea.
>
> Switch to Metal.

Also, update Vuforia Engine to a new 7.5 version. Black screen problems must be solved. And use the official release of Xcode 10 (10A255), not beta.

P.S. What iPhone are you using? You're writing you used iPhone 8 but console says: `Starting camera with profile for iPhone10,4, 720.1`.

Comment: I updated Unity and Vuforia and set Graphics APIs back to Metal. Problem is that with Metal I get this error when opens view controller with Unity AR: `UnityGfxDeviceWorker (38): EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and when I tried to fix it before I found in forums that I should remove Metal and use OpenGL ES.

Comment: Could you send me a screenshot of your code with this message?

Comment: Delete `OpenGLES2` and `Metal`. Try just `Auto Graphics API` tick. And how many MOV files are you using in your scene?

Comment: It seems to me that Unity has a bug regarding Metal. There's several posts and I don't see if the users solved the problem or not....

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Graphics APIs in Unity. Metal Does not supported in latest Xcode Version and replace Metal to OpenGLES2 or OpenGLES3.